# How to override the sales > order > Create new orders button in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, sales-order

I am new to Magento 2.

I tried overriding `sales > order > Create` new orders button from Admin panel. 
I am not getting the proper XML file to override.

I found

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/templates/control/button/default.phtml

and block file 
`Magento\Ui\Component\Control\Button`.

Can anyone help me in overriding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_UI/templates/control/button/default.phtml

Comment: Yeah.. I tried this. If i place a button in this. The button is displayed on all the admin panel screen.